# Port Expander Read via i2c in uboot

Tags: i2c, u-boot

I have a customized hardware with a port expander (PCA9555) that is connected via i2c to my SOM. The port expander is on bus 2 and is device 23. Now I need to read the value of Port P0 in a part of the u-boot environment. So i need to use the i2c commands. I have the following code but i can first test it on the hardware on Monday so my question is if somebody uses the same port expander and can tell me if my code is correct?! Thanks

```
    const int bus = 2;
const int device = 0x23;
int ret = i2c_set_bus_num(bus);
if (ret) {
    return 0;
}

ret = i2c_probe(device);
if (!ret) {
    uint8_t value;
    i2c_read(0x23, 0x00, 1, &value, 1);
}
```

Comment: Why?! U-Boot has the driver for this GPIO expander: *drivers/gpio/pca953x_gpio.c*. Enable it in the configuration and provide a correct DTS. Use `gpio` command instead.